# failed to open stream: No such file

Tags: php, codeigniter

when i update my project from codeigniter 2 to codeigniter 3.1.0 am getting error like this

> "Warning: include(C:\wamp64\www\hosteliam\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\hosteliam\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269"`.
>   this is my line on exception

```
ob_start();
include($templates_path.$template.'.php');
$buffer = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $buffer;
```

where line 269 is `include($templates_path.$template.'.php');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry the problem was the missing of error folder in views and now i found it out